# Dynamically generated jQuery functions stop working when multiple instances

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dynamically-generated

I have a chat application that works similar to hangouts.  When you click on a user the chat div is generated.  A simple feature I have is to allow them to press enter in a textarea to send the text, which works fine but if I have multiple dynamically generated jQuery functions only the LAST function will still work.  I assume its stopping the previous instances from running.  How do I fix this?

- Again when the user starts a chat it loads the scripts for that chat session because I assume I need a unique ID rather than a class name so I could pass the ID to the database - probably not the most efficient way to do things I know:

  ```
  echo "$('#im-textbox".$receiver_id."').on('keyup', function(event){

   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        //$(this.form).submit()
         var dataset = $('#im-form".$receiver_id."').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data/add-chat.php',
            data: dataset,
            method: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        $('#im-textbox".$receiver_id."').val('')
       return false;

     }
    });
  ";
  ```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this...

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#im-textbox".$receiver_id."', function(event){
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          //$(this.form).submit()
           var dataset = $('#im-form".$receiver_id."').serialize();
          $.ajax({
              url: 'https://easyrepair.us/manage/data/add-chat.php',
              data: dataset,
              method: 'post',
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
              }
          });

          $('#im-textbox".$receiver_id."').val('')
         return false;

       }
  });
```